# x-editable with meteor textarea no line breaks and date timezone issue

Tags: timezone, meteor, x-editable

I'm currently trying to work in bootstrap x-editable to my meteor application. I'm using the atmosphere package for this: https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-x-editable-bootstrap. I'm having a couple of issue so far which are:

- When I select a date using the date data-type I get a javascript date object back that is 4 hours behind what I actually picked(assuming this is because I'm in -4 timezone).
- When I edit a textarea, the line breaks are saved to the database, but when bring up the editable to edit it the line breaks are striped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be the intended behavior. Its hard to be sure without more information.

With the date, javascript stores date in unixtime. This is because its very easy to switch timezones and not worry about having javascript itself having to keep track of DST and the other complications of keeping time.

If you use `new Date(<the javascript timestamp>);` you should get the time in your timezone.

With the textarea it looks like some kind of text-encoding conversion is taking place. You should check to see what the character codes of those stripes are and convert them to newlines like `\n`. One scenario this could occur is if you're copy-pasting stuff with a different encoding into the textarea.

Comment: in the "success" event of the x-editable when the type is date you get a javascript date object not a javascript timestamp, so passing the new value into a ```new Date()``` constructor gets me the same value as before. What I have done is dove into the source code for the datepicker plugin and found that they substract the timezone offset multipled by 60,000 from the dates ```getTime()``` method and then create a new date with that and return it. The textarea I ended up swapping on save event ```/\r?\n/```'s for br tags and vice versa on the edit event.